# Changing style of certain cells in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I'm trying to change the color of certain cells in a DataGridView depending on wether the value is the same as in other cells. Sadly though, it's not working. This is the code which I thought should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < 8; j++)
        for (int k = 8; k < 20; k++)
            if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[k].Value)
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
dataGridView2.Refresh();
```

All columns are created with typeof(int) so it shouldn't be a type problem. Also debugging showed my program does enter the if-clause, yet still it doesn't display the changes.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you positive your program enters the if-clause?  I tried setting the BackColor on a specific cell in a datagridview and it worked just fine.

Comment: where are you writing this code ?

Answer (score 1):

I am doing this in one of the apps I work on.  Near as I can figure, the best way to do it is to override the DataGridView.CellFormatting event.

In my app, there are four boolean properties on each row of the datasource, I want to add a colored box for each of the properties that is true.

```
    void uxGrid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
             var item = uxGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as NiftyThing;
             if(item != null)
             {
                 if(item.Property1)
                 {
                     e.CellStyle.SelectedBackColor = e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                     //Don't display 'True' or 'False'
                     e.Value = string.Empty;
                 }
                 else if(item.Property2)
                 ...
             }      
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

I hope that helps!